# Вылетает org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Модель мини магазина

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String username;

private String password;

@Transient
private String password2;

private String email;

//...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Cart cart;

//getters and setters
```

Cart:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Cart {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
private List<BuyProduct> buyProducts;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

//getters and setters
```

BuyProduct:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyproduct")
public class BuyProduct {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
private Cart cart;

//getters and setters
```

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String productname;

private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
private List<BuyProduct> buyProducts;

private Long price;

//getters and setters
```

Здесь я пытался создать в одном из контроллеров мапу на продукт -> количество продуктов в корзине.

```
@GetMapping
public String cart(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                     @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,
                     Model model) {

    Map<Product, Integer> productMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (BuyProduct currentBuyProduct : user.getCart().getBuyProducts()) {
        Product product = currentBuyProduct.getProduct();
        if (productMap.containsKey(product)) {
            int count = productMap.get(product);
            productMap.put(product, ++count);
        } else {
            productMap.put(product, 1);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Но в строчке с условием цикла вылетает ошибка
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ru.study.simpleshop.models.Cart.buyProducts, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Пробовал ставить в Cart @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER), так там вообще сервер не поднимается. Пробовал метить с помощью Transactional - тоже не помогает. Ощущение, что я просто модель неверно выстроил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую угадать.

Эта ошибка вылетает при попытке вытащить ленивую коллекцию через user-а, который @AuthenticationPrincipal User user?

Смущает этот @AuthenticationPrincipal. User во время логина извлекается из базы и сохраняется где-то в сессии http в качестве принципала?
Тогда при последующих запросах он и сущности, на которые он ссылается, практически стопудова больше не привязаны ни к какой сессии и транзакции в манагере сущностей. И поэтому из него больше нельзя извлечь ленивые коллекции.

Вам нужно каждый раз извлекать свежую копию user-а. Примерно (очень примерно, потому что даже близко не знаю как там через спринг это делается) так

```
public String cart(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                 @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,
                 Model model) {

    user = entityManager.find(User.class, user.getId());

    Map<Product, Integer> productMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (BuyProduct currentBuyProduct : user.getCart().getBuyProducts()) {
```

Comment: Да круто, спасибо) Только я использую репозитории, поэтому вместо entityManager заавтовайрил UserRepository, грубо говоря, но логику понял. Я чето видимо плохо разобрался с этим @AuthenticationPrincipal. Смотрю вроде пользователь прилетает автоматом. Вроде как не должно было ничего подвести. А вот оказывается не все так просто :) А да, все работает, проверил)

Comment: Да кстати, пометить аннотацией Transactional тоже надо. Без этого та же ошибка будет вылетать.

Answer (score 0):

1) Помечайте функцию получения продукта из базы @Transactional
2) Если уже это не поможет то, переопределяйте этот бин в конфиге

```
@Bean
public OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter() {
    return new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
}
```